# sort NSArray with objects

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

Supposing NSArray has several objects which belong to two classes,

```
@interface FWNewsObj:NSObject
 {
  NSString *newsTitle;
  NSDate *newsTime;
 }
 @end




@interface FWPhotoObj:NSObject
 {
  NSString *photoTitle;
  NSDate *photoTime;
 }
 @end
```

I'd like to sort the NSArray with object's title (or time). However the title variable in each class has different names.

Then How can I do the sort?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a custom compare method that both your classes implement. It must take one object as a parameter and return an `NSComparisonResult` (`NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`)

You can then use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` with your own comparison method.

Example:

In FWNewsObj:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTitle:(id)obj
{
    NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[FWNewsObj class]] || [obj isKindOfClass:[FWPhotoObj class]], @"Don't know how to compare %@ to %@", self, obj);
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[FWPhotoObj class]]) {
        return [newsTitle compare:[(FWPhotoObj *)obj photoTitle]];
    } else {
        return [newsTitle compare:[(FWNewsObj *)obj newsTitle]];
    }
}
```

In FWPhotoObj:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTitle:(id)obj
{
    NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[FWNewsObj class]] || [obj isKindOfClass:[FWPhotoObj class]], @"Don't know how to compare %@ to %@", self, obj);
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[FWPhotoObj class]]) {
        return [photoTitle compare:[(FWPhotoObj *)obj photoTitle]];
    } else {
        return [photoTitle compare:[(FWNewsObj *)obj newsTitleTitle]];
    }
}
```

It would actually be easier to just define a title method in both classes that wraps either the photoTitle or the newsTitle. Then you can just use `NSSortDescriptor` with `title` as the key.

Comment: both classes implement the same selector? But the parameter of selector is the class instance. Then it will cause crash as the newsObj will call the FWPhotoObj's method.  Or May be I was wrong, and  can you say sth more detail and a sample is better.

Comment: I've added an example. As the parameter is of type `id`, it can be either a FWPhotoObj or a FWNewsObj (or anything else), you have to decide based on its class how to compare it.

Comment: you're right. I set a property with the same name in classes. Basically this is not a question as I think it can be avoided through the class design.

Answer (score 2):

What is instantly coming to my mind is(If I am understanding the Q correctly) :

- 1st create a dictionary, with titleNames as the keys, and value as the objects
- Sort the keys array simply
- Then create a sorted array of objects pulling them out of the dictionary, on basis of this sorted keys array